# Make random pixel movement run more efficiently

Tags: python, performance, pygame

My code uses three random numbers and some if statements to move a pixel randomly. Using cProfiler, it turns out the function is quite inefficient.

```
s = self.surrounding()
surroundingBool = [False if i == None else True for i in s]

r1 = random.random()
r2 = random.random()
r3 = random.random()

if r1 <= 0.333:
    if r3 < 0.5 and not surroundingBool[4]: self.x += 1
    elif not surroundingBool[3]: self.x -= 1
elif r1 <= 0.666:
    if r3 < 0.5 and not surroundingBool[6]: self.y += 1
    elif not surroundingBool[1]: self.y -= 1
else:
    if r2 < 0.25 and not surroundingBool[7]:
        self.x += 1
        self.y += 1
    elif r2 < 0.5 and not surroundingBool[2]:
        self.x += 1
        self.y -= 1
    elif r2 < 0.75 and not surroundingBool[5]:
        self.x -= 1
        self.y += 1
    elif not surroundingBool[0]:
        self.x -= 1
        self.y -= 1

self.x %= width
self.y %= height
    self.pos = self.y * width + self.x
```

Hopefully this is quite self explanatory but I can provide context as required.
How can I make these if else statements faster or more efficient?

The full code can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/EuutUVjS) if needed.

Comment: FYI, your second line can be simplified to `[i is not None for i in s]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a different approach that you can dismiss if you believe if differs from your pixel movement method.  Since there is a maximum of eight possible movements to neighboring pixels in a 2-dimensional pixel array, you can define a constant `list` of movements and pair them up with an index that refers to the pixel resulting from said movement.

From my interpretation of your code, this is something you could define in the `__init__` method of your `pixel` class.

Set up:

```
changes_1d = (-1, 0, 1)
changes_2d = [(i,j) for j in changes_1d for i in changes_1d if i or j]
self.movements = tuple(enumerate(changes_2d))  # Assign pixel index to each movement
```

Contents of `self.movements`:

```
0 (-1, -1)
1 (0, -1)
2 (1, -1)
3 (-1, 0)
4 (1, 0)
5 (-1, 1)
6 (0, 1)
7 (1, 1)
```

Why set this up?  Now we can make use of `random.choice()` to quickly select a random 2-D pixel movement, and we can check whether this move is valid by using the index returned alongside the (dx, dy) movement pair:

```
def move(self):
    s = self.surrounding()
    surroundingBool = [i is not None for i in s]

    pixel, movement = random.choice(self.movements)

    if surroundingBool[pixel]:
        self.x += movement[0]
        self.y += movement[1]
```

**NOTE:** This assumes that there is an equal probability of moving to any one of the eight surrounding pixels.

However, I believe that there may also be a great deal of inefficiency with the `self.surrounding()` function, particularly in this line:

```
PAI = allPixels[(self.x + x) % width][(self.y + y) % height] if allPixels[(self.x + x) % width][(self.y + y) % height] != None else None
```

You are checking whether the pixel is not None, then assigning it to `PAI`.  Although if it is None, you assign None to `PAI`, making the `if else` check redundant.  The following statement is equivalent:

```
PAI = allPixels[(self.x + x) % width][(self.y + y) % height]
```

I would offer more recommendations, but there is plenty of code there to make sense of.  Keep searching for ways to make improvements!

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help, it's much appreciated!

Comment: I get an error after implementing this: `AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'remove'`

Comment: My apologies!  I have changed my answer accordingly.  `changes_2d = ((i,j) for j in changes_1d for i in changes_1d)` should use square brackets instead of round brackets, as `tuple` does not have a remove attribute, whereas a `list` does.  I decided to make `self.movements` a `tuple` as it is constant and will not edited in your code (`tuple`s are faster than `list`s).

Comment: I've added a condition to the generator such that it never creates the `(0, 0)` entry, a little cleaner.